# Adding raw SVG code to HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

Earlier this day, I have succeed in converting SVG file to JPEG using javascript. The main steps are:

1. Get SVG image from a url
2. Add image to HTML5 Canvas
3. Convert the Canvas to JPEG encoded in base64

I replicate the [getImageFromUrl](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/basic.html#L442) function on jsPDF-master to achieve this.

```
var getImageFromUrl = function (url, callback) {
    var img = new Image,
        data, ret = {
            data: null,
            pending: true
        };
    img.onError = function () {
        throw new Error('Cannot load image: "' + url + '"');
    }
    img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        // Grab the image as a jpeg encoded in base64, but only the data
        data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').slice('data:image/jpeg;base64,'.length);
        // Convert the data to binary form
        data = atob(data)
        document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        ret['data'] = data;
        ret['pending'] = false;
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(data);
        }
    }
    img.src = url;
    return ret;
}
```

From that function, the image to be converted is actually a file. In my case, I don't have a file but only the raw code (text when you open a SVG file with text editor).

My question is:

How do you add raw code of a SVG file into the HTML canvas? Is this process also have .onload event attribute like image object?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a "raw" (inline) SVG to image by converting it to a Blob and then use that as an image source:

```
function drawInlineSVG(ctx, rawSVG, callback) {

    var
        /// create Blob of inlined SVG
        svg = new Blob([rawSVG], {type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"}),

        /// create URL (handle prefixed version)
        domURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self,
        url = domURL.createObjectURL(svg),

        /// create Image
        img = new Image;

    /// handle image loading
    img.onload = function () {

        /// draw SVG to canvas
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);     
        domURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        callback(this);
    };

    img.src = url;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var rawSVG = '<svg ... >';

drawInlineSVG(ctx, rawSVG, function(img) {
    console.log('done!');
});
```

An error handler should of course be included for production code (not shown here).

**Important to note:** You cannot draw inline SVG's if they contain external references (CSS styles, images and so on). This is due to [browser's security policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=SVG/SVG_as_an_Image#Restrictions). You would have to convert all external references to inline data (ie. images to data-uris and so on).

Comment: I also found this link (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas), it might be useful.